# how to sort according to size of subdirectories when using du -sh * command?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, centos, du

```
du -sh *
275M    fusionforge_g
50M     git
99M     httpd
181M    php-doc
4.0M    pirate3
3.4G    qt
1.1M    vim-addon-manager
126M    wp-and
```

this output is out of order now, how to make this output ordered according to the size of subdirectories?

@vstm  the version of my core util is less than 7.5, so the solution in https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size cannot solve my problem.

```
rpm -qa | grep core
coreutils-5.97-19.el5
policycoreutils-1.33.12-14.2.el5
```

@Leonid Volnitsky
sort -nr not works when -h option is used:(

```
du -sh * | sort -nr
275M    fusionforge_g
181M    php-doc
126M    wp-and
99M     httpd
50M     git
4.0M    pirate3
3.4G    qt
1.1M    vim-addon-manager
```

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: [How can I sort du -h output by size](http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size)

Comment: Agree with the close (and I'd written a lovely answer too!)

Comment: @vstm the version of my core util is less than 7.5

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
  command du -sh */ | sort -nrh
```

Comment: not works, the version of my core util is less than 7.5

Comment: I forgot `-s` options for `du`, but otherwise it should work with any coreutils version.  The `command` - is bash built-in.  Do you use bash or something else? You can try without it, it just removes aliases to `du` if you have any.  Try this: `du -s */ | sort -nr`

Comment: du -s is not human readable, i need du -sh:(

Comment: Does your sort supports `-h` ?

Comment: yes, but du -sh * | sort -nr is out of order:(  sort -nr not works when -h option is used:( i have paste details above:)